# Google Analytics not working with domain emailid

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

I have integrated Google Analytics into my Android application. I followed all the set up instructions and registered for Google analytics. It is working fine with my Gmail account, I am receiving all the updated number of users and screens also but not working with some other domain email id (Ex:XXX@XXX.com) which is purchased from Gmail.

This is the code I am using in every screen.

```
com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker tracker = ((MYApplication)
getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        tracker.setScreenName(TAG);         tracker.send(new
HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

Can some one please help me?

Comment: Have you configured the tracking id in your android app. Just verify the tracking id you are using in your android app is from the registered app from domain email id.

Comment: I cross checked it . The tracking Id was from the domain email id only

Comment: I have created an application in the domain email id , i got a tracker id and i pasted it into my code . Still its not working